# how to fix the CCS installation error on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, code-composer

I have been trying to install the CCS(code composer studio) in the ubuntu server running in VM through SSH.
I'm doing this for the first time, and I have hit an error, searched online but couldn't find any help.

I have installed the preliminary lib requirement from TI website, that is required for the CCS, while installing the CCS its showing this error on tmp folder in the linux server.

> CCS_ERROR: Install exited with error code
>
> no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

I searched the folder and found, there is no env $DISPLAY as i do not need it.
Can someone kindly help me to get rid of this error.

Comment: When you call ssh, are you using the -X flag? (ssh -X ...)

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to this installation process on Ubuntu, could you please brief me where should i use -X,

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from TI employee, which fixed the above mentioned error.
Adding it here, just so that if anyone hits the same error.

> without a display specified, the only option is to run the installer
>   in unattended mode to remove the GUI dependency. This will do a
>   COMPLETE install of CCS.
>
> To install all of ccs in unattended mode you need to use the following
>   command line:

```
<installername> --prefix $HOME/ti  --mode unattended
```

Or

```
sudo <installername> --prefix /opt/ti --mode unattended
```